# Java switch statement with += / -= operators

Tags: java

Really simple question, but can't figure this out. Why does y compute to 2 in the (Java) code below?

```
int x = 2;
int y = 2;
switch (x * 2) {
    case 4: y += 1;
    case 6: y -= 2;
    default: y += 1;
}
```

Comment: Is this your homework? (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework)

Answer (score 5):

It falls through from case 4 to case 6 to the default, so it increments (new value: 3), decrements by 2 (new value: 1) and then increments (new value: 2).

The compiler should have warned you about the fall-through, at least if you use `-Xlint`. Never ignore compiler warnings out of hand, and always compile with `-Xlint` :)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add `break`:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 2;
switch (x * 2) {
    case 4: 
        y += 1;
        break;
    case 6:
        y -= 2;
        break;
    default: y += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not add break after case.  So it execute all statement. 
y=y+1-2+1; 2

Switch statement should be -

```
int x = 2;
int y = 2;
switch (x * 2) {
    case 4: y += 1;break;
    case 6: y -= 2;break;
    default: y += 1;
}
```

Then y would be 3

Answer (score 1):

In a switch statement all cases below the first matching case will be executed unless you add a `break;` statement.

If you expect y to be `1` you need to do:

```
int x = 2; 
int y = 2;  
switch (x * 2){  
case 4: y += 1; 
break;
case 6: y -= 2; 
break;
default: y += 1; 
}
```